I tried to use a RANKX function in power BI but I'm getting an error as "A circular dependency was detected"
Rank =
RANKX (
    ALLEXCEPT (
        'Account Level AUM',
        'Account Level AUM'[InvestmentAccountLegalName],
        'Account Level AUM'[InvestmentAccountNumber],
        'Account Level AUM'[InvestmentAssetClassTypeName],
        'Account Level AUM'[AssetCategoryName],
        'Account Level AUM'[AccountBaseCurrencyCode],
        'Account Level AUM'[ListingUID],
        'Account Level AUM'[InstrumentUID],
        'Account Level AUM'[Date_Quarter_Acc]
    ),
    [Edate_Acc],
    ,
    DESC,
    DENSE
)

I have data coming in on all days of a quarter but I need to consider the data with the max(position_date) for each quarter.

A circular dependency was likely arise because your RANKX function is referencing column within the ALLEXCEPT filter itself -  [Edate_Acc]. This creates a circular loop where Power BI tries to calculate the rank based on Edate_Acc, but Edate_Acc might depend on the rank itself.
Check Dependencies: Ensure that [Edate_Acc] is not dependent on the measure you are trying to create. This means verifying that [Edate_Acc] is calculated independently and does not reference the Rank measure directly or indirectly.
Option 1: Pre-calculate the date column
Create a new calculated column before defining the RANKX function. This column can simply return the [Edate_Acc] value.
Use this newly created calculated column instead of [Edate_Acc] within the RANKX function.
Option 2: Use EARLIER function(Not sure this will work, but it doesn't hurt to try)
RANKX (
    ALLEXCEPT (
        'Account Level AUM',
        'Account Level AUM'[InvestmentAccountLegalName],
        'Account Level AUM'[InvestmentAccountNumber],
        'Account Level AUM'[InvestmentAssetClassTypeName],
        'Account Level AUM'[AssetCategoryName],
        'Account Level AUM'[AccountBaseCurrencyCode],
        'Account Level AUM'[ListingUID],
        'Account Level AUM'[InstrumentUID],
        'Account Level AUM'[Date_Quarter_Acc]
    ),
    EARLIER([Edate_Acc]),
    ,
    DESC,
    DENSE )

OR Try this
Rank =
VAR EdateAccValue = [Edate_Acc]
RETURN
RANKX(
    ALLEXCEPT(
        'Account Level AUM',
        'Account Level AUM'[InvestmentAccountLegalName],
        'Account Level AUM'[InvestmentAccountNumber],
        'Account Level AUM'[InvestmentAssetClassTypeName],
        'Account Level AUM'[AssetCategoryName],
        'Account Level AUM'[AccountBaseCurrencyCode],
        'Account Level AUM'[ListingUID],
        'Account Level AUM'[InstrumentUID],
        'Account Level AUM'[Date_Quarter_Acc]
    ),
    EdateAccValue,
    ,
    DESC,
    DENSE
)

